# When should I use the "superproject" pattern?

Tags: c++, cmake

Some libraries, such as [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm), use a "superproject" pattern, where consumers of the library, such as libcxx, should live inside of the libraries' folder-structure. In the case of LLVM, this is `llvm/projects`.

This seems quite limiting, as it makes it harder use the library when there are other folder-structure constraints.

Why was this descision made, and what are some reasons to use such a layout?

Comment: I think that only the first part of your question (`Why was this descision made`) may be answered **objectively**. As for the second part - `when should such a layout be used?` - answers to it could be very *opinion-base* (as any other design policy suggestion).

Comment: I think there could be objective reasons to use such a project layout, which would answer "when should such a layout be used?"

Comment: This "objective reasons" are just *advantages* of the approach. For decide whether use given approach or not, you should compare its advantages with ones of other approach.